# bs4 parses different html than browser

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-applications, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape farefetch.com (https://www.farfetch.com/ch/shopping/men/sale/all/items.aspx?page=1&view=180&scale=282) with Beautifulsoup4 and I am not able to find the same components (tags or text in general) of the *parsed* text (dumped to soup.html) as in the browser in the dev tools view (when searching for matching strings with CTRL + F).

There is nothing wrong with my code but redardless of that here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# imports
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# parse website
url = 'https://www.farfetch.com/ch/shopping/men/sale/all/items.aspx?page=1&view=180&scale=282'
response = requests.get(url)
page_html = response.text
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# write parsed soup to file
with open("soup.html", "a") as dumpfile:
    dumpfile.write(str(page_soup))
```

When I drag the soup.html file into the browser, all content loads as it should (like the real url). I assume it to be some kind of protection against parsing? I tried to put in a connection header which tells the webserver on the other side that I am requesting this from a real browser but it didnt work either.

1. Has anyone encountered something similar before?
2. Is there a way to get the REAL html as shown in the browser?

When I search the wanted content in the browser it (obviously) shows up...

[image]

Here the parsed html saved as "soup.html". The content I am looking for can not be found, regardless of *how* I search (CTRL+F) or bs4 function find_all() or find() or what so ever.

[image: the parsed content is not the same as the content displayd in the browser]

Comment: The page almost certainly uses Javascript to manipulate DOM objects (adding classes, styles, tags..) on the fly - and `BeautifulSoup` doesn't execute JavaScript. What information do you need to get from the page?

Comment: Search for that in the Network panel. That will tell you if it was really in a response.

Comment: Hey Andrej thanks for the answer. I want to parse the product parameters (such as name, image link, details page link, price etc) for every product that is on sale (discount)... any idea on how to achiev that? @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is an example how you could extract some information from products that are on discount:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.farfetch.com/ch/shopping/men/sale/all/items.aspx?page=1&view=180&scale=282"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for product in soup.select('[data-test="productCard"]:has([data-test="discountPercentage"])'):

    link = 'https://www.farfetch.com' + product.select_one('a[itemprop="itemListElement"][href]')['href']
    brand = product.select_one('[data-test="productDesignerName"]').get_text(strip=True)
    desc = product.select_one('[data-test="productDescription"]').get_text(strip=True)
    init_price = product.select_one('[data-test="initialPrice"]').get_text(strip=True)
    price = product.select_one('[data-test="price"]').get_text(strip=True)
    images = [i['content'] for i in product.select('meta[itemprop="image"]')]

    print('Link          :', link)
    print('Brand         :', brand)
    print('Description   :', desc)
    print('Initial price :', init_price)
    print('Price         :', price)
    print('Images        :', images)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Link          : https://www.farfetch.com/ch/shopping/men/dashiel-brahmann-printed-button-up-shirt-item-14100332.aspx?storeid=9359
Brand         : Dashiel Brahmann
Description   : printed button up shirt
Initial price : CHF 438
Price         : CHF 219
Images        : ['https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/14/10/03/32/14100332_22273147_300.jpg', 'https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/14/10/03/32/14100332_22273157_300.jpg']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Link          : https://www.farfetch.com/ch/shopping/men/dashiel-brahmann-corduroy-t-shirt-item-14100309.aspx?storeid=9359
Brand         : Dashiel Brahmann
Description   : corduroy T-Shirt
Initial price : CHF 259
Price         : CHF 156
Images        : ['https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/14/10/03/09/14100309_21985600_300.jpg', 'https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/14/10/03/09/14100309_21985606_300.jpg']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me:
instead of the following code

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

use

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html")
```